# MySQL query to do nothing (like pass)

Tags: mysql

Many languages have a construction that fills a syntactic position of a statement but has no effect: `pass` in Python, `\relax` in TeX, `CONTINUE` in Fortran, `;` in C and Perl.

What is its equivalent in MySQL? That is, a query that would be syntactically correct but have no effect -- apart from confusing expressions like `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0`.

This is useful when the queries are generated automatically and at some point the generation procedure is expected to generate a query but there is no action to do.

Comment: perhaps `/* */` a comment block? or `--`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE false
```

or simpler in MySql 8.0+:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE false
```

return nothing, if this is what you mean when you say *no effect*.

Comment: Never seen the `DUAL` before. What does that stand for?

Comment: *a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced* from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Yes, I saw back in the 5.6 reference (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#idm44969551420800) but I see no real difference (`select 1+1;`  and `select 1+1 from dual;` perform the same) aside from this `no effect` requirement. Is it an acronym or what is its purpose?

Comment: `select 1+1` and `select 1+1 from dual` are exactly the same in all versions of MySql. But the `where` clause is allowed only with `from dual` in versions prior to 8.0

Comment: `dual` is a dummy table with only 1 row and used by many databases like MySql, Oracle, Postgresql. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table and https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-dual-table.php

Answer (score 1):

`DO 0;` is another option for MySQL No-op.

Answer (score 0):

First what comes to mind is just `SELECT null` or something similar.

Edit:
Unlike `SELECT null`, `set @noop = null` does nothig

Comment: This does something. It returns NULL.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood what 'does nothing' means

Comment: No-op SQL queries are useful if you want to ping the server to stop your connection from being automatically closed for inactivity

Answer (score 0):

When doing from cli client you can also just call the quit function as you enter like this:

```
mysql -e '\q'
```